# Как убрать лишние отступы и ничего не сломать

Tags: html, css

Доброй ночи. получил такое замечание по коду от ревьювера

1)Браузер автоматически добавляет марджины сверху и снизу всем тегам заголовков (h1-h6) и параграфов (p). Нужно пройтись по всем классам на странице и по удалять лишние марджины.
Вот вопрос в следующем
есть ди какой то способ сразу узнать где лишние отступы ? или на каждый элемент в браузере пкм и там отслеживать , меняется что то или нет ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто добавьте в самом начале CSS-кода:

```css
* {
  pading: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Это сбросит все внешние и внутренние отступы. Если вы работаете с препроцессором и имеете несколько файлов, соединяющихся в один, то прописывать это нужно в начале самого главного файла.

Comment: Спасибо , это то что нужно.